# Get multiple URL parameters using useParams() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, url-parameters, react-functional-component

I am trying to pass multiple parameters in a url using React-Router 5.1 and the useParams hook in a Functional component.

However I encounter really strange behavior.

I paste the url into the client.

Url:

```
 http://localhost:3000/onboarding/eventId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04d1&groupId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04dc&userId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04da
```

Path:

```
<Route path = '/onboarding/:eventId?/:groupId?/:userId?' exact component = {OnboardingViewController} />
```

Strange thing #1: 
I have to make the params optional, or the browser just hangs forever.

I fish them out using all these strategies:

```
    var   {  eventId, groupId, userId } = useParams();
    var   {  eventId } = useParams();
    var   {  groupId } = useParams();
    var   {  userId  } = useParams();
```

Strange thing #2:
Unfortunately when trying to use these params this happens:

```
{userId: undefined, eventId: "eventId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04d1&groupId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04dc&userId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04da", groupId: undefined}
```

The hook just takes the first param and interprets the rest a part of te first.

Strange thing #3:
Since adding this url params query accessing the page laoding is extremely slow, multiple seconds.

What am I not seeing, doing wrong?

ANSWER:

What I was doing wrong:
I was using url/eventId=123. 
This is wrong. 
You just need to supply the resource at the right place in the URL url/1/2/3.

correct:

```
http://localhost:3000/onboarding/5e9aaf4fc27583001190834e/5e9aaf60c275830011908361/5e9aaf4fc275830011908357
```

You then tell the Router that those things will be called eventId & groupId & userId.

```
 <Route path = '/onboarding/:eventId/:groupId/:userId' exact component = {OnboardingViewController} />
```

Then you can access these in the component using the userPrams() hook.

```
var  { eventId,  groupId, userId } = useParams();
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You're mixing up "params" and "search". if the url is `/onboarding/1/2/3/` then the result of `useParams` will be `{ eventId: 1, groupId: 2 userId: 3 }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still do not understand. 

var params = useParams();

var userId = params.userId // should work 


But params is undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your Route structure and Route doesn't match

If you want to use params in your URL would be
`http://localhost:3000/onboarding/5e9a173f9166f800128c04d1/5e9a173f9166f800128c04dc/5e9a173f9166f800128c04da`

And your Route component would be:

```js
<Route path = '/onboarding/:eventId/:groupId/:userId' exact component = {OnboardingViewController} />
```

And then you can use this in the `OnboardingViewController`component:

```js
 var   {  eventId, groupId, userId } = useParams();
 console.log(eventId,groupId,userId)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing up match parameters with URL query parameters.

The URL query parameters can be retrieved from the [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) object using the [`useLocation`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

Given URL `http://localhost:3000/onboarding/?eventId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04d1&groupId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04dc&userId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04da`

```
{
  pathname: '/onboarding/',
  search: '?eventId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04d1&groupId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04dc&userId=5e9a173f9166f800128c04da'
}
```

*would need a route `path="/onboarding/"` though*

You can use a QueryParameter processing library to then convert these to a map object.

If you could massage your URL to be in the form:
    http://localhost:3000/onboarding/5e9a173f9166f800128c04d1/5e9a173f9166f800128c04dc/5e9a173f9166f800128c04da

Then the route `path='/onboarding/:eventId/:groupId/:userId'` can then match the path params returned by `useParams`.

```
const { eventId, groupId, userId } = useParams();
```